# Remove Orphaned WCF service host from Windows services

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF service host in my services that was installed, but then deleted without it being uninstalled. Normally, I would go to the directory and remove the WCF Service Host using the /uninstall flag, but since the folder got deleted...there is no place for me to go. How can you uninstall or remove this reference?

Answer (score 0):

Open regedit, and look in the key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services.
Look for the subkey of your service and remove it.